# Disable character removing keys in a JavaFX TextField

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

The title pretty much says it all. I need to disable character-removing keys in a JavaFX TextField. By character-removing keys, I mean DEL and SUPPR.

Right now, this is what I have:

```
mytextfield.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {          
            if (event.getCharacter().matches("[0-9]")) {
                // some stuff that works perfectly here
            }
            event.consume(); // to cancel everything but 0-9 keys
        }
    });
```

But for some reason, even though the event gets consumed, the end character still gets deleted when pressing delete.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: First thought coming to my mind: saving `TextField#getText` to a (local) variable and restoring it after consumption (if no number was added).

Comment: Works for me if I catch the DELETE key event. Please provide a MCVE.

Comment: @Roland the handle(KeyEvent) method gets called, but even if the event is consumed, the last character still gets deleted. The snippet I gave you is pretty much as minimal as what I use

Comment: That's not **complete**.

Answer (score 3):

`KEY_TYPED` will fire an event only after pressing a key that generates a UTF output. `KEY_TYPED` event will not be generated at `BACK_SPACE` and `DELETE` key press. Use the `KEY_PRESSED` event instead.

```java
mytextfield.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {          
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE || event.getCode() == KeyCode.DELETE) {
                event.consume(); // to cancel character-removing keys               
            }
        }
    });
```

Putting the `event.consume()` inside the if block will cancel only these buttons. The others will work as usual.

Comment: Since this was asked in 2016, I no longer have the environment where this issue used to happen. I doubt your answer, but I can't validate whether or not it solves the issue