# How can I disable the spacebar in a textfield in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I got a question. I would like to disable the space bar completely for that textfield so there are no spaces in my input. How is that possible?

```
if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                    System.out.println("Spacebar key detected!");
                    textfieldName.setText(textfieldName.getText().substring(textfieldName.getLength() -1));
                }
            });
```

This is what I found, but I would like to disable the spacebar completely. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks for answering :)

Comment: you can swallow the event.

Comment: You are probably looking for is the [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) . It takes a `valueConverter` and (more importantly) a `filter`. The filter is used for All input (including clipboard events). Just look at the documentation of those classes, it should be pretty straight foreward how to implement the mechanism you want

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871377/disable-character-removing-keys-in-a-javafx-textfield) will help

```
mytextfield.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {          
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                event.consume(); // to cancel space key               
            }
        }
    });
```

---

**Another way** is to [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) it like [@n247s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5231001/n247s) suggested in the comments

Comment: I gave the event filter method a try and consuming the event still didn't prevent a space in the text field, yet it was being registered?